# How to get list of absolute paths from a given filtered JsonPath expression

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am using following library:

```
com.jayway.JsonPath
version 2.4.0
```

I am processing a json string using the shared JsonPath (filtered) expression, and I need to update different values to the different matching json-nodes at the same time, for that I need list of all matching absolute paths.

however I used this scala code, the output is close but not expected:

```
val conf = Configuration.builder().options(com.jayway.jsonpath.Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build()
val pathList: net.minidev.json.JSONArray = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(str).read("$.vehicles[*].registrations.[?(@.name=='regNo')].value")
```

but this returns:

```
["$['vehicles'][0]['registrations'][0]['value']","$['vehicles'][0]['registrations'][2]['value']","$['vehicles'][0]['registrations'][3]['value']"]
```

Below is the input scenario:

**Input Json**

```
{
"id": "123",
"coverageDate": "2017-11-22",
"vehicles": [
    {
        "terms": {
            "type": "Debit",
            "holder": {
                "name": "Orix Asia Ltd"
            }
        },
        "owned": false,
        "registrations": [
            {
                "name": "regNo",
                "value": "ABC123",
                "price": 12.22
            },
            {
                "name": "abcNo",
                "value": "DEF123s",
                "price": 13.23
            },
            {
                "name": "regNo",
                "value": "XYZ123",
                "price": 12.22
            },
            {
                "name": "regNo",
                "value": "ABC123",
                "price": 12.22
            },
            {
                "name": "customNo",
                "value": "DEF123s"
            }
        ],
        "detail": {
            "region": "Custom"
        }
    }
]
}
```

**Given JsonPath filtered expression:**

```
$.vehicles[*].registrations.[?(@.name=='regNo')].value
```

**Query:** how to get list all the matching **absolute paths** like below:

```
$.vehicles[0].registrations[0].value
$.vehicles[0].registrations[2].value
$.vehicles[0].registrations[3].value
```